# Create scheduled background task with Jersey

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, jersey-2.0, java-ee-6

I have RESTful web service which uses Jersey and I need to create a background task which will do some actions (calling DB, etc.).
I found some examples which use ServletContextListener and it works.

```
public class Scheduler implements ServletContextListener {

private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;

@Inject
private MyDBService service; //doesn't work

@Override
public void contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
    scheduler = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor();
    scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
        //want to use service here
        }
    }, 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Override
public void contextDestroyed(ServletContextEvent event) {
    scheduler.shutdownNow();
}}
```

But I also need to @Inject some services here and seems like it doesn't work here.
I also found some examples with EJB, but I can't use it here.